# Как сверстать данный блок без медиа - выражений?

Tags: css, email

Пытаюсь сверстать адаптивное email - письмо. Есть вот такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При 540 и выше элементы должны перестраиваться в ряд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли такое сделать без медиа - выражений? Я не нахожу иного способа. А с медиа - выражениями ничего не выходит. Gmail и Yandex их стили тупо не хотят наследовать.

Comment: Скорее всего можно, но в письме всё равно вряд ли заработает. Хотя изменение выравнивания меня смущает.

Comment: А вообще, наверное всё-таки не получится - элементов же 3, а не 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Gmail можно передать @media запросы, но нужно максимально идеально написать CSS. Вам поможет форматирование из jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/

(кнопочка tidy в правом верхнем углу при наведении на область CSS)

Вот рабочий для Gmail код адаптаций:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
          @media only screen and (max-width:768px)  {
            .desktop-view{display: none !important;}
          }

         @media only screen and (min-width:769px) {
            .mobile-view{display: none !important;}
          }
        </style>
</head>

<body>



    <some other stuff here>

<table class="module mobile-view" table-view="mobile" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" data-type="code" role="module" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td> mobile content here </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="module desktop-view" table-view="desktop" role="module" data-type="code" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td> desktop content here </td>
    </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моб приложение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Своровано отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701247/how-do-i-write-a-media-query-for-gmail

Яндекс же вырезает @media. Боюсь для него ничего придумать не выйдет. Без media запросов такую адаптацию сделать не получится.

**Возможное решение без media** - сделать одно письмо и для ПК и для телефонов, ограничив ширину самого письма условными 600 пикселями, а оставшееся по краям место залить фоном.

Т.Е. по сути выводить на ПК версию для мобильных телефонов.

Comment: Спасибо. Этот способ действительно работает у меня. По крайней мере в Gmail. К сожалению ни в yandex, ни в mail корректно не отображается. Придётся искать компромисс, чтобы упростить вёрстку.

Comment: Попробовал поиграться с display:flex; и минимальными значениями ширины. https://jsfiddle.net/adudnik/q29vw1yL/ но он не поддерживается большинством мобильных приложений/браузеров. Так что да, придется переделывать верстку.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<tr>
 <td align="center">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0; max-width: 600px;">
   <tr>
    <td style="padding:0;text-align:center;font-size:0;">
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;" >
    <tr>
    <td width="200" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
    <![endif]-->
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%; max-width:200px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="margin: 0; padding:0; text-align:left; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.3; font-weight: bold; color: #000000;">
       контент 1
      </td>
     </tr>
     <!--padding bottom-->
     <tr><td><div style="height: 25px; line-height: 25px; font-size: 20px;">&nbsp;</div></td></tr>
     <!--padding bottom-->     
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    </td><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
    <![endif]-->
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%; max-width:200px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="margin: 0; padding:0; text-align:left; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.3; font-weight: bold; color: #000000;">
       контент 2
      </td>
     </tr>
     <!--padding bottom-->
     <tr><td><div style="height: 25px; line-height: 25px; font-size: 20px;">&nbsp;</div></td></tr>
     <!--padding bottom-->     
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    </td><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
    <![endif]-->
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%; max-width:200px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="margin: 0; padding:0; text-align:left; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.3; font-weight: bold; color: #000000;">
       контент 3
      </td>
     </tr>
     <!--padding bottom-->
     <tr><td><div style="height: 25px; line-height: 25px; font-size: 20px;">&nbsp;</div></td></tr>
     <!--padding bottom-->     
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <![endif]-->                           
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
```